# How to call one of two C++ template functions with condition

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, c++14

There is a class with two member template functions: fun1(), fun2().
I want to call one of the functions decided by a const bool class member : willCallFun1.
There is a solution like fun() in the code, but the if-else branch will check every times while fun() is called. I want avoid branch.
Since when the Foo object is constructed, const bool willCallFun1 has been set, so which function of fun1 and fun2 will be used can already be determined.

```
class Foo {
public:

  const bool willCallFun1;

  Foo(bool b) : willCallFun1{b}{
  }

  template<typename T>
  void fun1(T t) {
    std::cout << "fun1 "<< t << "\n";
  }

  template<typename T>
  void fun2(T t) {
    std::cout << "fun2 "<< t << "\n";
  }

  template<typename T>
  void fun(T t){
    if (willCallFun1) fun1<T>(t);
    else fun2<T>(t);
  }

};

int main() {
    Foo f1{true};
    f1.fun(123);
    f1.fun("hi");

    Foo f2{false};
    f2.fun(456);
    f2.fun("hello");
}
```

If fun1, fun2 are non-template functions, I can add a new member in the class, such as a function pointer or std::function to bind one of them at the constructor.
I can't find a way to do it when they are template functions.
I would be very grateful if someone could answer.

Comment: Does the `bool` have to be set at runtime? Can you make it into a template parameter instead?

Comment: Yes, in my project the bool is decided by the user, so it need to be set at runtime.

Comment: Do you think calling `std::function` will be faster than one, probably correctly predicted (if you are concerning with this), branch?

Comment: *"but the if-else branch will check every times while fun() is called. I want avoid branch"* - Did you (micro-)benchmark this? How are you certain the compiler isn't doing a simple computed goto here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how compilers handle branching.
I may have a misunderstanding that branching is an expensive operation.
Since the condition is a constant, will the compiler's branch prediction be quite accurate on the above example?

Comment: @WayneTseng If you call `fun` a couple of times I would assume that the branch prediction will be pretty accurate, yes. That's why I suggest that you _test_ if the branchless approach in my answer is actually faster. I suspect that it will not be.

Comment: somewhat relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array. As a general rule of thumb you should not be afraid of certain stuff havin negative impact on performance unless you measured and *know* that it actually has impact. Branching is what cpus do all day and they are really good at it (or rather good at not branching when you'd expect one)

Comment: The linked post is so cool. I never thought about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't make `willCallFun1` into a template parameter and use `if constexpr` to decide which function to call, you could create an array of member function pointers and lookup the correct one using `willCallFun1` as an index variable.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void fun(T t) {
    using fun_sig = void(Foo::*)(T);

    static constexpr fun_sig funs[] = {&Foo::fun2<T>, &Foo::fun1<T>};

    (this->*funs[willCallFun1])(t);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8ze5Pe4c8)

I'd test if this is actually faster than having a simple `if` though. I've done this before with disappointing results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
This is a cool approach that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: imho last sentence is important. You are trading a branch vs a indirection. A priori there is not much reason to expect one being better than the other.

Comment: @WayneTseng You're welcome! It _can_ be useful in certain situations, but I suspect this is not one of them :-)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Indeed! And the `static` _may_ be counted as a branch if one is picky. Initializing it without `static` would make it truly branchless I guess.

Comment: I'm starting to learn about branch prediction.
I was convinced it would be better to keep the original branch.

Comment: I think branch predictor works better than jump predictor.

Comment: @WayneTseng A branchless approach is probably very good when it doesn't cost even more than leaving it up to the CPU to predict and sometimes branch.

Comment: @WayneTseng I'd actually also expect the `if` that always takes the same direction to be faster than the array. But don't trust anybody but your code. You really need to measure it to know

Comment: It seems like gcc and clang aren't good enough even at `-O3` to optimize this well. Code is generated that looks like `auto* pmf = funs[willCallFun1]; if (is_virtual(pmf)) [[likely]] { pmf = this->vtable[get_offset(pmf)]; } jump_to_function(pmf); }`, so this actually creates an extra branch+jump.